# Initialize JS Scripts on jQueryMobile Page

Tags: javascript, initialization, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I am working on a single-page app using jQueryMobile 1.0 Beta 2 and testing on iOS 4.3.5 Mobile Safari.

As we can see here:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

The jquery mobile api is very specific on the new way to initialize scripts with the ajax calls. I am using the pageCreate() event from the jquery mobile api to initialize my scripts:

```
$('.ui-page').live('pagecreate',function(event){
  //my js init codes
});
```

But somehow, it is not so effective and I am having trouble on one of my key views which doesn't initialize.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the pageshow event:

```
    $('.ui-page').live('pageshow', function(event) {
        // js init codes
    });
```

This is working for me in my app. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Hi, I am facing some problem in initializing JS code, i tried pageshow event but on each visit call to JS Init Code increases, ex. on third visit to page, this method get called three times on fourth visit it get called four times, my question is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724959/asp-net-mvc3-jquery-mobile-pages-ajax-code-binding-using-pageinit-event